Determining Safe C-Rate for Degraded Lithium Batteries: Design vs. Actual Capacity
Which capacity should be used to determine the C-rate for charging and discharging a lithium battery: the design capacity or the actual degraded capacity?
The purpose of this question is to ensure usage safety, especially when dealing with a degraded battery. Should we reduce the charging/discharging current to match the actual degraded capacity, or can we continue to use the design capacity?
Here are my assumptions:

The charging/discharging current might not be directly related to capacity but should be based on the internal resistance during charging and discharging, as well as the battery's heat dissipation capabilities at a given ambient temperature.
The degraded capacity might not significantly affect the internal resistance, allowing us to continue using the design capacity.
The degraded capacity might be highly related to internal resistance, as both depend on the number of movable ions in the electrolyte.
The charge and discharge current from the design parameters might be valid within certain limits, for example, when the actual capacity is greater than 80% of the design capacity.


This spec is determined by the manufacturer, and is different for different li-ion battery designs.

Your questions sounds as if you were to build a rechargeable battery using used rechargeable LiIo-batteries.

@r2d3, Actually, it just safety concern over keep using old degraded battery.  For example is it inscresing thermal runaway risk? What can we do to keep using it safely or at which threshold that we must throw it away?

Ask your battery manufacturer about the threshold. My local mains power supplier is performing primary regulation in the electricity net using roughly a thousand of spare batteries for electrical cars. Despite them being new they are installed in a way that one broken burning battery does not ignite neighbouring batteries in the warehouse. They already had had one burning battery (out of maybe roughly 1000) when I visited their site.

The specs taking into account design capacity when specs are expressed C-rate dependant should matter.
Degraded capacity may only be available if you do Coulomb counting and full charge/recharge cycles are available and happen frequently enough.
This may not be the case, though.
Temperature measurement is mandatory to prevent thermal runaway with could already start a 60°C. As surface temperature differ from internal temperature the use of a temperature model is recommended.
Cooling may contribute to hotspot generation and may require the use of more temperature sensors.

So you suggest that when the battery degraded, there is unknown region for safety usage, right? that why you reccommened to use temperature monitoring.

I am talking about capacity reduction before reaching the end of life.
